# Smith Normal Form of a companion matrix of monic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, smith-normal-form, companion-matrices

> Let $C(f)$ be the companion matrix of a monic polynomial $f(t) \in \mathbb{F}[t]$. I need to show that the Smith Normal Form of $tI - C(f)$ is equal to the diagonal matrix $\mbox{diag}(1,1,1,\dots,f(t))$.

A little bit baffled on how to begin. I've constructed the companion matrix and written out my monic polynomial. I think there are some relationships between equivalent/similar matrices of the form $tI-A$ that might help. But I'm definitely scratching my head on understanding how to link the Smith Normal Form to all of this.

Comment: Surely the usual "reduce to Smith Normal Form" algorithm gives this at once?

Comment: Perhaps? What is that algorithm?

Comment: If the Smith NF of a matrix $M$ is $d_1,d_2,\dots, d_n$ then $d_1d_2\dots d_k$ is the hcf of all the $k\times k$ minors of $M$. Apply this to $M=tI-C(f)$, it's clear that there's always a $k\times k$ minor $1$ for $k<n$.